# Blackjack game - Difficulty with Java - superclasses

Tags: java, arrays, blackjack

I'm creating a Blackjack program and I'm stuck, I would appreciate any help available.
I have a Player class and a Card class.

The below function (getHandValue) is meant to calculate the total value of the player's hand.

```
/*getHandValue - accessor that computes the total value of the 
player's current hand
*/
public int getHandValue(Card[] hand){
    int total = 0;

    for (Card card : hand){
        String rank = card.getRankName();
        total += card.getValue();

        if (rank.equals("Ace") && total < 11){
            total += 10;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

This method, printHand, is meant to print the contents of the player's hand and the value of the player's hand using getHandValue.

```
/* ISSUES
* printHand - accessor that prints the current contents 
of player's hand followed by value of player's hand
*/
public static void printHand(Card hand[]){
    int value = hand.getHandValue();

    for(int i = 0; i<hand.length; i++){
        System.out.println(hand[i] + "  ");
    }

    System.out.print("(value = " + value + ")");
}
```

I keep getting the error that "Cannot invoke getHandValue() on the array type Card[]" in the printHand method.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I'm sure its because of the way I structured these classes but I'm not sure where to even start

Thank you for your time

Comment: Why do you think the Card array has a `.getHandValue()` method?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the error, including the definition of the `Card` class.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an Array, and you need to expect its working as an array, you need to move your `hand.getHandValue();` inside the loop and let the value stay outside.

Like this:

```
public static void printHand(Card hand[]){
    int value = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<hand.length; i++){
        value += hand[i].getHandValue();
        System.out.println(hand[i] + "  ");
    }
    System.out.print("(value = " + value + ")");
}
```